# Storing spatial points in Symfony 2 / Doctrine 2 Entities?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, doctrine-orm

Symfony 2 doesn't have the spatial points datatype that MySQL supports. I couldn't find anything on the Doctrine 2 documentation about this particular data type, so, does anyone know how to work with points in Symfony 2? Also, how to query based on a radius? Thanks! :)

Comment: "spatial points datatype". Is this a fancy way of saying decimal datatype for storing lat/long information?

Comment: @MikePurcell No, it's the straight way of describing actual geospatial data http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/spatial-extensions.html

Comment: @PeterBailey: Thanks for the heads up. My something new for the day.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The easiest way would be to implement custom types for the spatial data types, and then declare custom DQL functions to make querying them simpler.

I wrote about this here: http://codeutopia.net/blog/2011/02/19/using-spatial-data-in-doctrine-2/

Answer (score 4):

Another option would be to use the djlambert/doctrine2-spatial bundle, found here: https://github.com/creof/doctrine2-spatial

No need to implement any custom stuff.

Comment: Have you used that bundle with deserialize? I tried it with JMS Serializer I can serialize, but it fails when I return the same JSON and try to deserialize.

Comment: No I haven't tried that. I didn't have a need to work with JSON on the project where I needed the spatial stuff.

Answer (score 1):

If you speak french, youd could get some inspiration with another article here : http://blog.fastre.info/2012/02/doctrine2-2-2-et-types-geographiques/

This classes were build for a Postgresql + Postgis Database.

Comment: this link is dead